# What is $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}$, when $F(y, y')=f(y^2)g(y')$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Lets say I have for example the function:

$$F(y, y')=f(y^2)g(y'),$$

where $y=y(x),\;y'=y'(x)=\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}$. What is

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=?$$

Is it simply:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=f(y^2)g'(y')?$$

What if $f(y^2)=\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\left(y^2\right)=2yy'?$

My main question is that, when we are taking the derivative of $F(y,y')$ with respect to $y'$, do we need to take into consideration that the function's $f(y^2)$ expression might involve the term $y'$?

In other words in my example, is:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=f(y^2)g'(y')$$

or is it:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=f'(y^2)g(y')+ f(y^2)g'(y')$$

Hope my question is clear, I got a small confusion with my homework problem :)

Comment: $y$ and $y'$ are independent co-ordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your help =) @Chinny84, but I'm not completely out of the blue yet ;D Do I need to take into consideration that when $y'$ is changing that $f(z(y))=f(y(x)^2)$ might also change in the function $F(y,y')=f(y^2)g(y')$? =)

Comment: Not really. Take a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) to reassure you of the fact. If you taking the derivative w.r.t t then you do as you have done above.

Comment: Thank you @Chinny84, so $F_{y'}=f(y^2)g'(y')$. I will take a look at the wiki-page :)